# Why using "getSize" method provided by selenium will only return the layout(setting) size rather than viewport(scaled) size?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Currently, I am using selenium 4.13.0 version's provided "getSize" method on an element. What I am trying to get is the actual displayed size of that element in the browser， which was scaled into twice of the setting size， since the target element's parent has a scale attribute which was set to twice. Thus, may I ask whether there is any other way provided from selenium to get the actual displayed size（which can also be called the viewport size）for the targer element？

I have attached the screenshot below to illustrate the problem and hope get some suggestions or hints？（As you can see， the original setting is （40 21）and the actual size displayed in the browser is （80 42）and when I use "getSize method provided by selenium，it only return the setting size （40 21）"）

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFPJ6.png)

Workarounds tried：

1. One way I also tried using is "getRec" method provided by selenium too， which also only returned the origianl setting size. （X）
2. The other way I tried is to use javascript method "element.getBoundingClientRect()" can work and return the viewport size. （Y）